# LWC to display records grouped by RecordType Name

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, wire

I'm trying to get a list of all CaseT records under their respective recordtype name in a lwc component.

So, 
CaseT Recordtypename 1

1. CaseT A
2. CaseT B
3. CaseT C

CaseT Recordtypename 2

1. CaseT X
2. CaseT Y
3. CaseT Z

I have tried the following:

APEX:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static Map<string, List<CaseT__c>> caseTrxMap(Id caseId){
    case caseRec = getCaseConsumer(caseId);
    String consumerId ='';

    if(caseRec != null ){
        consumerId = caseRec.AccountId;
        System.debug('@@consumerId:: '+consumerId);
    }

    Map<String, List<CaseT__c>> mapObj = new Map<String, List<CaseT__c>>();        
    List<RecordType> rTList = [SELECT Name, Id FROM RecordType 
                               where SobjectType ='CaseT__c'];

    for (CaseT__c transaxItem : [SELECT RecordType.Name, ConsumerName__c 
                                                  FROM CaseT__c 
                                                  where ConsumerName__c =:consumerId]) {            

        if(!mapObj.containsKey(transaxItem.RecordType.Name)) {
             mapObj.put(transaxItem.RecordType.Name, new List<CaseT__c>());
               mapObj.get(transaxItem.RecordType.Name).add(transaxItem);
        }
        else {
           mapObj.get(transaxItem.RecordType.Name).add(transaxItem);
        }            
    }
    system.debug('mapObj'+mapObj);
    return mapObj;
}
```

Here's the JS controller:

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import caseList from '@salesforce/apex/caseTrxMap.caseTrxMap';

export default class myLWC extends LightningElement {
@track accounts;
@track error;

@wire(caseList)
wiredAccounts({ error, data }) {
    if (data) {
        this.accounts = data;
        this.error = undefined;
    } else if (error) {
        this.error = error;
        this.accounts = undefined;
    }
}
```

}

Here's the HTML:

```
<template>
    <template if:true={accounts}>
        <template for:each={accounts} for:item="account">
               <p key={account.Id}>Account - {account.Name}</p>
        </template>
   </template>
 </template>
```

I'm able to get the recordtype names and values in the map of maps (Map>), but I'm at a loss as to how the **wiring** works (@wire: a small description would be great). I'm unable to put the values on the HTML (planning on Accordion, trying my luck)

Kindly point me to the right direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your method should have (Cacheable = true)

*"If an Apex method is annotated with @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true), you can invoke it from a component via the wire service."*

```
    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable = true)
```

2. You should pass caseId

   `@track caseId;`

   `@wire(caseList, { caseId: '$caseId' })
   wiredAccounts({ error, data }) {
       if (data) {
           this.accounts = data;
           this.error = undefined;
       } else if (error) {
           this.error = error;
           this.accounts = undefined;
       }
   }`
3. You cannot iterate through the map using

   `template for:each={accounts}` It works only for List, Array, not for Map.

   To iterate by specific List you need to do something like that:

   `template for:each={accounts.YourRecordTypeName}` it allows you to iterate only by one record Type.

Here is my proposition. Create a wrapper instead of map and return it in your method.

**APEX**

```
public class RecordTypeWrapper {
    @AuraEnable
    public String recordTypeName;

    @AuraEnable
    public List<CaseT__c> cases;

    public RecordTypeWrapper(String recordTypeName, List<CaseT__c> cases) {
       this.recordTypeName = recordTypeName;
       this.cases = cases;
    }
}


@AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
public static List<RecordTypeWrapper> caseTrxMap(Id caseId){
    case caseRec = getCaseConsumer(caseId);
    String consumerId ='';

    if(caseRec != null ){
       consumerId = caseRec.AccountId;
       System.debug('@@consumerId:: '+consumerId);
    }

    List<RecordTypeWrapper> recordTypesList = new List<RecordTypeWrapper>();

    Map<Id, RecordType> recordsTypeMap = new Map<Id, RecordType>([SELECT Name, Id FROM RecordType 
                                                                  WHERE SobjectType ='CaseT__c'])

    List<CaseT__c> allCasesList = [ SELECT RecordType.Name, ConsumerName__c 
                                    FROM CaseT__c 
                                    WHERE BC_ConsumerName__c =:consumerId ];
    List<CaseT__c> casesForRecordType;
    for (Id recordTypeId : recordsTypeMap.keyset()) {

        casesForRecordType = new List<CaseT__c>();//reset

        for (CaseT__c case : allCasesList) {
            if (case.RecordType.Name == recordsTypeMap.get(recordTypeId).Name) {
                  casesForRecordType.add(case);
            }                 
        }

        recordTypesList.add(
            new RecordTypeWrapper(
               recordsTypeMap.get(recordTypeId).Name,
               casesForRecordType
           )
       );

    }

    return recordTypesList;
}
```

**LWC**:

```
<template for:each={accounts} for:item="account">
     {account.recordTypeName}
     <template for:each={account.cases} for:item="case">
         {case.ConsumerName__c} 
     </temlate>
</template>
```

Wire description [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.apex).

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful solution. Records were easier to display with wrapper than with the map directly.

Comment: I am glad that I could help! :D